# C macro defines variable length value

Tags: c, macros

I has implemented own `tmpnam()` function for creating temporary files. I use following defines for adjust this one:

```
/* The length of random string. In /tmp/test143276 is 143246 */
#define RND_ROUND 6
/* Used as a minimal bound produced by number generator      */
#define RND_MIN 100000
/* Used as a maximum bound produced by number generator      */
#define RND_MAX 1000000
```

As you can see the real needed macro is `RND_ROUND` and others are derivative to pass to the number generator. And the formula for generating is:

```
RND_MIN = 1 and [RND_ROUND-1] zeros
RND_MAX = 1 and [RND_ROUND] zeros
```

**Question:** How can I create some macro which will produce `RND_MIN` and `RND_MAX` based on `RND_ROUND` at compile time?

**Example:**

```
#define RND_ROUND 6
// somehow define those RND_MIN and RND_MAX
...
int32_t random = g_rand_int_range(generator, RND_MIN(RND_ROUND), RND_MAX(RND_ROUND));
```

Comment: Can you use power function ??

Comment: Can you use binary pattern ?

Comment: Well, generally I can, but I think it's not preferable  way as `RND_MIN` and `RND_MAX` are never changed at runtime, thus calculating them every call (in function like `create_tmp_file`) wastes resources.

Comment: What is binary pattern?

Comment: @uuser966467 Binary pattern means -- if `RND_ROUND` is `3` then you will get `100` that is `4`. If you looks binary pattern of this number then its stored as `0000 0000 0000 0100`  in two bytes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the power function to do the work.

```
#define RND_MIN (pow (10, RND_ROUND-1))
#define RND_MAX (pow (10, RND_ROUND))
```

Or depending on the passed argument.

```
#define RND_MIN(val) (pow (10, (val)-1))
#define RND_MAX(val) (pow (10, (val)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If I am correct you can use power function:

```
#define RND_MIN(RND_ROUND)  pow(10, RND_ROUND - 1)
#define RND_MAX(RND_ROUND)  pow(10, RND_ROUND)
```

You may like to read: [How to simplify this power equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345052/how-to-simplify-this-power-equation)

Comment: Does this mean that it is not at compile time and it will be executed at runtime?

Comment: @user966467 `power` function will be called at runtime

Comment: @user966467 read [Binary to Decimal](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454716/binary-to-decimal), so you have to use `pow()` function no other-way I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to forget about `RND_ROUND`: this is compile time, anyway!

```
#define RND_BASE 1000000
#define RND_MIN RND_BASE
#define RND_MAX (RND_BASE*10)
```

Now, if you really need `RND_ROUND`, `RND_MIN` and `RND_MAX` at compile time and not being expanded to `pow`, assuming your `RND_ROUND` is not  you may branch it with `#if` (note that `g_rand_int_range` is limited to `gint32`, so `RND_MAX`<`2^31`=`2'147'483'648`<`10^10` is possible):

```
#if RND_ROUND <= 1
#    define RND_MIN 1
#elif RND_ROUND <= 2
#    define RND_MIN 10
#elif RND_ROUND <= 3
#    define RND_MIN 100
#elif RND_ROUND <= 4
#    define RND_MIN 1000
#elif RND_ROUND <= 5
#    define RND_MIN 10000
#elif RND_ROUND <= 6
#    define RND_MIN 100000
#elif RND_ROUND <= 7
#    define RND_MIN 1000000
#elif RND_ROUND <= 8
#    define RND_MIN 10000000
#else
#    define RND_MIN 100000000
#endif

#define RND_MAX (RND_MIN*10)
```

This will also be safer, limiting `RND_ROUND` so that there will not be integer overflows.